# Macbook pro retina setting resolution to 2880 restored to 1440 after restart system

Tags: macos, settings, macbook-pro, resolution

System is Mountain Lion, these steps will reproduce the problem:

1. Select a primary resolution in System Preferences pannel, Displays. Select the 'Best for Retina display' (Other resolution in this pannel is also OK).
2. Use the SetResX to set the resolution to 2880x1800 (I tried some other programs, the same result).
3. Restart the system or log out the current account.

Then after login again, the resolution will restore to the resolution in setp one.

Is there a way to keep the resolution to 2880x1800 permanently?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution here:

http://wineskin.urgesoftware.com/tiki-view_blog_post.php?postId=51

> This isn't exactly a Wineskin related post, but... with the new Retina
>   Macs not having a way to truly change the resolution, I threw together
>   a little app that uses the WSReso command line tool I made for older
>   versions of Wineskin for changing resolutions before RandR was added
>   to XQuartz... it uses WSReso and its just an Applescript GUI front end
>   that lets you change resolutions, including knocking that Retina
>   Display Macbook Pro up to a true 2880x1800.  Works on any Macs for
>   changing resolutions around... its very simple, but effective.
>
> http://wineskin.urgesoftware.com/Special/Change Resolution.app.zip
>
> EDIT: update
>
> if you want to just have an app that automatically goes to your max
>   resolution that you can put in your startup items... use this
>
> http://wineskin.urgesoftware.com/Special/SetRes.app.zip

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.